# emberjs-1.0 problems with link-to- and serialize when router-has-a-dynamic-segment

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-router

I have a **[jsfiddle with nested route](http://jsfiddle.net/GQdbD/1/)** where I am nesting one  dynamic routes **timeSlot** inside another dynamic route **appointment**. Inside the appointment template I have a **#link-to 'timeSlot'**. When I click that link, the **timeSlot template** is never rendered and in the console I see:

```
 This link-to is in an inactive loading state because at least one of its parameters presently has a null/undefined value, or the provided route name is invalid.
```

This is the router. Note that if I changed the **timeSlot route** from a dynamic route to a normal route, that is to something link this, **this.resource('timeSlot')**, the error goes away and the template is displayed. The route needs to be dynamic, as it accepts dates passed in via users click from a calendar.

It is a small jsfiddle and 95% of the code in **[the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GQdbD/1/)**  is pasted in this question:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('appointments', {path: "/"}, function(){ 
    this.resource('appointment', {path: "/:appointment_id"}, function(){
       this.resource('timeSlot', {path: '/:day'});                       
    });     
  });   
});
```

The appointment route

```
App.AppointmentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params){ 
   },

   setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('content', model);
   }
 });
```

The TimeSlot route

```
App.TimeSlotRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){   
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
   this._super(controller, model);
   controller.set('content', model);       
  },

  serialize: function(dateText) {
    /*
   return { 
      day: //this.controllerFor('timeSlot').today.pushObject(dateText)};
       */
  } 
 });
```

The appointment template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="appointment">
   <br/>
   {{#link-to 'timeSlot' [2013-07-18]}}click timeSlot{{/link-to}}

    {{outlet}}
 </script>
```

The time Slot template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="timeSlot">
<h3> from timeslot template</h3>


{{outlet}}
</script>
```

**update**

For this route: **this.resource('timeSlot', {path: ':appointment_id/:day'});**
Explicitly passing values for each of the dynamic segment to link-to, via **{{#link-to 'timeSlot' id=this day=['today'] }}click timeSlot{{/link-to}}** in this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GQdbD/3/)**, has now made it possible to hover over the link and see **'#/2/dateText'**, where each slash  segment is meant to be the value for the dynamic segment. Before passing in the value for the dynamic segment, all i saw when I hovered over the link was **/#'** suggesting the dynamic segment were not being picked.

It is still not working though. Because It using hard-coded values passed in the serialize method and not those passed to link-to.

**update 2**

This version is working though #linkTo doesn't seem to be calling serialized method.
http://jsfiddle.net/GQdbD/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hard to tell what you're trying to do since all of your `model` hooks are empty.  (Are they actually empty in your app?)  In general, when you call `link-to`, `transitionTo`, or `transitionToRoute` Ember expects you to pass in a live model.  In these cases the `model` hook on your route is skipped and the model that you pass to `link-to` is used instead.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for coming to the rescue again. I will be grateful , if you suggests ways to fix the issues in this **[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472769/emberjs-1-0-computed-property-and-template-not-refreshed-when-data-changes)**. It is about a template not refreshing when a computed property changes or about a computed property not being called the 2nd time.. Thanks.